# How do you set the default foreground color for code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, customization

The option *Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font* lets you set the default font only, not the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic colors are defined in the Preferences in 'General > Editors > Text Editors' in the 'Appearance color options'.

Individual editors may define many more colors which may override these settings. For the Java editor these are in the Preferences in 'Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring'.

Comment: I have set *General > Editors > Text Editors > Foreground Color* as black, and then disabled the Syntax Coloring for Local Variables in Java, but local variables still shows up in dark blue instead of black.  Nothing shows up in black, actually.

Comment: I think the Java editor uses the 'Others' color (in the Syntax Coloring list) as the fallback if nothing else is enabled.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.